# Can I fix an incorrect file move in Mercurial much later?

Tags: mercurial, rename

We've all been there at some point -- you move a file using something other than Mercurial's `hg move` command and commit and push your changes only to realize your mistake much later. Is there any way to later inform Mercurial that there is a relationship between the "old" path and the "new" path?

I've tried playing with `--after` but that just seems to error out unless you happen to catch the problem before committing the problem changeset:

```
  > hg move OLD_PATH NEW_PATH --after
  OLD_PATH: The system cannot find the file specified
  abort: no files to copy
```

In my particular situation, this change was committed by a coworker across a messy private branch (or two) and then merged to our `default` branch and pushed to our main repo, so it's already spread out to the entire team.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, are you sure that the rename wasn't detected? Mercurial will detect moves where the file remains unchanged (i.e. where it wasn't a rename + edit) by default and record it as a rename. Verify that it wasn't actually detected with `hg log -f NEW_PATH`.

If it wasn't recorded as a rename, do a branch off the old commit with a proper rename and merge:

```
hg update -r ORIGINAL_COMMIT    # Go to the commit before the rename
hg move OLD_PATH NEW_PATH       # Record the rename
hg commit                       # Commit the rename
hg update default               # or whatever your main branch is
hg merge -r tip --tool :other   # '-r tip' is technically optional
hg commit                       # Commit the rename to the main branch
hg log -f NEW_PATH              # Verify that it worked
```

Note that `--tool :other` will prioritize the "other" branch (i.e. the new commit) and learn the proper history from there.

---

Postscript: It is also possible to alter the history after the fact, but for that you need the evolve extension. With that, you can alter a commit after the fact (with `hg amend` or `hg commit --amend`) and propagate the change through your history (with `hg evolve --all`) [1]. However, other members of your team may also need the evolve extension; plus, the shared repository that you push to/pull from needs to be set up for it (as a [non-publishing repository](https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases#Publishing_Repository)). While this is possible, the setup effort, and the training your team may need to become proficient may not be worth it; also, other Mercurial-related tools may not understand it and become confused by it. In short: this is currently an advanced option that you should only use with full understanding and if the alternatives are insufficient.

[1] Note that `hg evolve` will not actually modify history, but create a new alternate history, related to the original one via so-called obsolescence markers. The old history can be viewed with `hg log --hidden` (or other commands with the `--hidden` flag).

Comment: Thanks! In this case it was a move & edit, part of a bigger refactor. I was also aware of evolve & other history modifying changes, but I hadn't thought of just doing the move and merging it -- I'll give that a try.